# notepad++ xml node regex find and replace

Tags: regex, xml

can you tell me the what to search for in notepad++ in order to find all nodes with the optioncode 09 below and delete that node?  For example, I would like to be able to search on the below xml and delete the first entry and be left with is below that.

I tried to searching for `<Vehicle>.*?</Vehicle>` which works to replace a blank value, however I want to also add criteria to search for the 09 value in the entire node.  Is it possible to add a search condition for the ">09<" text string value?

Search here:

```
  <Vehicle>
    <InvoiceDateTime>2016-03-20T00:00:00</InvoiceDateTime>
    <InvoiceChargeCents>63</InvoiceChargeCents>
    <OptionCode>09</OptionCode>
    <JobEndDateTime>2016-03-19T00:00:00</JobEndDateTime>
    <AuthorizationCode />
  </Vehicle>
  <Vehicle>
    <InvoiceDateTime>2016-03-20T00:00:00</InvoiceDateTime>
    <InvoiceChargeCents>63</InvoiceChargeCents>
    <OptionCode>35</OptionCode>
    <JobEndDateTime>2016-03-19T00:00:00</JobEndDateTime>
    <AuthorizationCode />
  </Vehicle>
```

Return the entry below:

```
  <Vehicle>
    <InvoiceDateTime>2016-03-20T00:00:00</InvoiceDateTime>
    <InvoiceChargeCents>63</InvoiceChargeCents>
    <OptionCode>35</OptionCode>
    <JobEndDateTime>2016-03-19T00:00:00</JobEndDateTime>
    <AuthorizationCode />
  </Vehicle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach consists in matching the `<Vehicle>` opening node, and then restrict dot matching so that it could match neither opening nor closing `Vehicle` nodes with a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
<Vehicle>(?:(?!</?Vehicle>).)*>09<.*?</Vehicle>\R*
```

The **`.` matches newline** option should be *enabled*.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ0vE3/1), replace with an empty string.

The `(?:(?!</?Vehicle>).)*` is a tempered greedy token that matches any text up to the first `>09<` after the closest `<Vehicle>` opening node.

[image]

Note that `\R*` matches zero or more newline sequences (either CRLF, or CR, or LF).

Also please note that a more efficient pattern will be the unrolled version of the above pattern:

```
<Vehicle>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/?Vehicle>)[^<]*)*>09<.*?<\/Vehicle>\R*
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ0vE3/2)

It matches the same text, but is more efficient with larger texts.

Comment: Awesome, looks like this works perfectly, even when there are multiple blocks without the >09< above.  Thanks for you help!